# Subdivision of geometric simplicial complex

Tags: co.combinatorics, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology

Let $\{v_0,v_1,\cdots,v_n\}$ be $n+1$ points in $\mathbb{R}^N$ which are geometrically independent. We define their convex hull to be a geometric simplex. Using this we can define geometric simplicial complex.

For an abstract simplicial complex, we know that two of its subdivisions have a common subdivision (given in Spanier). For a finite geometric complex, we know the same statement is true. Is the same statement true for geometric simplicial complex when the number of simplices are infinite?

If the statement is true, please give a reference.

Comment: By "geometrically independent" do you mean none of them is an affine combination of the others?

Comment: Yes. By geometrically independent means none of them is affine independent of others. This language is used in a few books.

Answer (score 4):

If you're willing to restrict to locally finite simplicial complexes, then the answer is yes. See Chapter 3 of Hudson, Piecewise Linear Topology. In particular, a locally-finite simplicial complex is a PL space. Suppose you have two subdivisions $K$ and $L$. Then by Hudson's Theorem 3.6.C there are subdivisions $K'$ and $L'$ such that the identify map (which is certainly PL and proper) is a simplicial map $K' \to L'$. But then $K'=L'$.